# How to make a dinamic div dissapear after few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I want to make the FIRST door dissapear after 5 seconds when I click on the first button.
Then the second door, the third.. one after another.
So I should add the code in the function toogleDoor.

I tried with JQuery but I failed.

Do you have any suggestions?

`

```
<div class="backDoor">
    <div class="door5" id="door5">
        <div class="door4" id="door4">
            <div class="door3" id="door3">
                <div class="door2" id="door2">
                    <div class="door1" id="door1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="parola"></input>
  
    <button id="button1" onclick="toggleDoor(1)">
        Apri prima porta
    </button>
    <button id="button2" onclick="toggleDoor(2)">
        Apri seconda porta
    </button>
    <button id="button3" onclick="toggleDoor(3)">
        Apri terza porta
    </button>
    <button id="button4" onclick="toggleDoor(4)">
        Apri quarta porta
    </button>
    <button id="button5" onclick="toggleDoor(5)">
        Apri quinta porta
    </button>
    <script>
        
      function toggleDoor(door) {
    // Find the proper door
    element = document.querySelector('.door' + door); // With constructed reference

    
    if (element) { // does the door exist?
        if (checkParola(door)) { // proper password?
            element.classList.toggle("openDoor");
            // Here I want to make the selected door to dissapear after 5 seconds
    };
};
      };
```

`

Comment: u can use a promise to wait for 5 seconds, then execute your hide div function - `new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000)).then(() => { console.log('after 5 seconds') })`

Answer (score 1):

You could use setTimeout() to make the door dissapear. Just use an arrow function inside that toggles the class.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  element.classList.toggle("openDoor")
}, 5000)
```

This will prompt a class change after 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds). Inside of the openDoor class in your CSS, you must use display:none; or visibility: hidden; to make the above code work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the setTimeout function.

```
<div class="backDoor">
    <div class="door5" id="door5">
        <div class="door4" id="door4">
            <div class="door3" id="door3">
                <div class="door2" id="door2">
                    <div class="door1" id="door1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="parola"></input>
<button id="button1" onclick="toggleDoor(1)">
    Apri prima porta
</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="toggleDoor(2)">
    Apri seconda porta
</button>
<button id="button3" onclick="toggleDoor(3)">
    Apri terza porta
</button>
<button id="button4" onclick="toggleDoor(4)">
    Apri quarta porta
</button>
<button id="button5" onclick="toggleDoor(5)">
    Apri quinta porta
</button>
<script>
    
  function toggleDoor(door) {
// Find the proper door
element = document.querySelector('.door' + door); // With constructed reference


if (element) { // does the door exist?
    if (checkParola(door)) { // proper password?
        element.classList.toggle("openDoor");
        // Here I want to make the selected door to dissapear after 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            element.style.display = "none";
        }, 5000);
    }
}
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is not clear enough, I didn't understand what you exactly want to do,
And if every door has it's own button and functionality, why you nested the divs inside each others.

---

But...

If you want to apply any function after a period of time, you can use the `setTimeout()` method, which takes two parameters, the first is the function and the second is the time in milliseconds:

```
setTimeout(dothing, 100)  // will apply "dothing" after 100 milliseconds

function dothing() {
    // your code here
}
```

And if you want to pass arguments to your function, so you can do that:

```
setTimeout( function() { dothing( params ) }, 100 )
```

---

If it understood your question wrongly, please explain it more to be able to help.